# The Omer during Shmita

Tags: sefirat-ha-omer, shmita, mincha-meal-offering, parashas-emor, behar

The original Omer was an offering of newly cut barley.

So what happened during the Shmitta year when there was no harvest? Presumably this offering was not brought?

Was there still a biblical requirement to count the days and weeks like we do now? (Some say the mitzvah we keep now is only Rabbinic).

Comment: Why couldn't they bring it?

Comment: @DoubleAA Because there was no harvest.

Comment: @loewian Whatever that means. There was wheat/barley.

Comment: @DoubleAA not that was permitted to be planted unless there was no other available.

Comment: @loe We're talking about harvesting not planting

Comment: @DoubleAA One generally doesn't reap what one doesn't sow.

Comment: @loewian Key word there is 'generally'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There was a *korban omer* even during *shemitah*. (Otherwise, how could one have eaten from *chodosh* in *chutz la'aretz*?) It came ideally from the "*sefiach*" (self-seeded produce); though if that wasn't available, it was imported from [Suryah](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=7&hilchos=36&perek=1&halocha=9&hilite=), or, if still necessary, planted in Israel and offered on the Altar (but not eaten by the priests). As such, all the related commandments were still applicable including *sefirath ha'omer*.

From *[Wikishiva](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%95%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%91%D7%94%3A%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%96%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%AA/%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%97%D7%AA_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%A8)* :

> מכיון שדין "מנחת העומר" לבוא מן התבואה החדשה, הרי
> שבשמיטה היתה מנחת העומר צריכה לבוא מספיחי תבואה שגדלה בשביעית.
>
> לצורך מנחת העומר היה צריך להתיר את שריפת קומץ המנחה הקדוש בקדושת
> שביעית, חרף איסור הפסד פירות שביעית.
>
> בשנת השמיטה היו בית הדין שוכרים שומרים שישמרו על הספיחים המיועדים
> למנחת העומר, "ואותן המעות שנותנים להם בשכרם (מתרומת הלשכה) הוא כאילו
> קונים בו העומר ושתי הלחם
> ...
> אם לא מצאו ספיחי תבואה בארץ ישראל, היו מביאים מסוריה; לא נמצאה בסוריה תבואה הראויה לעומר, מותר לזרוע תבואה לצורך העומר בארץ ישראל. "מנחת עומר" זו אמנם היתה קרבה על גבי המזבח, אך לא היתה נאכלת לכהנים, הואיל והבאתה היתה כרוכה בדחיית איסור זריעה בשמיטה.
>
> Since the *omer* offering must come from new grain, therefore it needed to come from the self-seeded growth of the sabbatical year. It was necessary to allow the burning of the *kometz* of the sabbatical produce in spite of the general prohibition of destroying sabbatical produce. During the sabbatical year, the court would hire watchmen to guard the self-seeded growth designated for the *Omer* offering... If they found no self-seeded growth in the land of Israel, thye would bring from Suryah; If they also found no fitting grain there, then it was permitted to plant grain for the purpose of the Omer in the land of Israel in which case it was offered on the altar but not eaten by the priests since its offering was bound with the overriding of the prohibition of planting during the sabbatical year.

See also, [Yerushalmi Shekalim 4:1 15b](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/b/r/r2504.htm), Rambam [Hilchos Shekalim 4:5](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=3&hilchos=18&perek=4&halocha=5&hilite=) (and [Hilchos Kiddush Hachodesh 4:15](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=2525)), and Meiri on Shekalim 4.

Comment: The article you cite cites no classical sources.

Comment: @DoubleAA That's the best I turned up so far with my preliminary search (and why I appended that rambam). Also, the OP didn't request any.

Comment: @loewian Why "chodosh in chutz la'aretz"--what about in Eretz Yisrael?

Comment: @wfb I assume the OP was assuming there wasn't any since it was forbidden to be planted during shemittah.

Comment: @Shamiach Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @Shamiach The key point they said about it being from the sefiach is borne out by the rambam I linked.

Comment: My ability to translate is good enough for that Rambam that was quoted.

Comment: Also Mishnah Shevi'is 1:4: רבי ישמעאל אומר, מה חריש רשות, אף קציר רשות, יצא קציר העמר.

Comment: @wfb do we pasken rabbi yishmael though?

Comment: @loewian I don't know, but it sounded familiar. Is there a machlokes le-dina or just on the derasha?

Comment: @wfb Thats not talking about shviis, rather R' yishmael is referring to regular shabbas, that the omer is Dochei Shabbas.